# Critical Error after Updraft Restoration

Tags: plugins, errors

I am having 'there has been a critical error on your website' I used updraft to restore my website to a different host. Immediately after restoring, it worked fine until the next day I start getting the error

Just to add, I can access my wordpress dashboard

Comment: It sounds like your site was working while DNS was still pointing to the old host, but now that DNS has propagated and you're actually seeing what's running on the new host, that is not working. Check to make sure that on the new host you have a database that matches your wp-config settings. On some hosts you use 'localhost' as the server; on other hosts you may need to reference a specific server name, it all depends on the host.

Comment: I have checked the database and it matches with the wp-config. Its localhost even on other websites i hosted on the same host

Comment: You may need to contact the new host, and/or the backup plugin author, for more specific help.

Comment: If you used a different URL during the migration process make sure you have updated the site url field in WP admin to the correct url. You may also need to perform a search and replace on the database to replace any instances of the wrong url with the correct one in the DB. Search for the "Better Search and Replace" plugin. Make sure you have a full backup first, and you can do a dry run to make sure it's going to find and replace only the data you want it to.